# Setting axis limit for plot

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure, axis

I want to set the limit for X axis in this plot from  `0 to 325`. When i am using `xlim` to set the limits (commented in the code). It doesn't work properly. When i use `xlim`, the entire structure of plot changes. Any help will be appreciated.[image]

```
figure
imagesc(transpose(all_area_for_visual));
colormap("jet")
colorbar('Ticks',0:3,'TickLabels',{'Home ','Field','Bad house','Good house'})
xlabel('Time (min)')
tickLocs = round(linspace(1,length(final_plot_mat_missing_part(2:end,1)),8));
timeVector = final_plot_mat_missing_part(2:end,1);
timeForTicks = (timeVector(tickLocs))./60;
xticks(tickLocs);
xticklabels(timeForTicks);
%xlim([0 325]);
ylabel('Car identity')
yticks(1:length(Ucolumnnames_fpm))
yticklabels([Ucolumnnames_fpm(1,:)])
```

Answer (score 0):

[`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) puts the data in little rectangles centered around integers `1:width` and `1:height` by default. You can specify what the x and y locations of each data point by adding two vectors to the call:

```
imagesc(x,y,transpose(all_area_for_visual));
```

where `x` and `y` are vectors with the locations along the x and y axes you want to place the data.

Note that `xlim` and `xticks` don’t change the location of the data, only the region of the axis shown, and the location of tick marks along the axis. With `xticklabels` you can change what is shown at each tick mark, so you can use that to “fake” the data locations, but the `xlim` setting still applies to the actual locations, not to the labels assigned to the ticks.

I think it is easier to plot the data in the right locations to start with. Here is an example:

```
% Fake your data, I'm making a small matrix here for illustration purposes
all_area_for_visual = min(floor(cumsum(rand(20,5)/2)),3);
times = linspace(0,500,20);      % These are the locations along the time axis for each matrix element
car_id_names = [4,5,8,15,18];    % These are the labels to put along the y-axis
car_ids = 1:numel(car_id_names); % These are the locations to use along the y-axis

% Replicate your plot
figure
imagesc(times,car_ids,transpose(all_area_for_visual));
%        ^^^    ^^^   NOTE! specifying locations
colormap("jet")
colorbar('Ticks',0:3,'TickLabels',{'Home ','Field','Bad house','Good house'})
xlabel('Time (min)')
ylabel('Car identity')
set(gca,'YTick',car_ids,'YTickLabel',car_id_names) % Combine YTICK and YTICKLABEL calls

% Now you can specify your limit, in actual time units (min)
xlim([0 325]);
```

Comment: Leungo. Sry, i didnot understand. I just want to change the limit of X-axis to 325 in this case.

Comment: @Venkat: I've added an example code, I hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to plot only part of the data in `all_area_for_visual`, given by a condition on `tickLocs`. So you should first condition the data, and then plot it:

```
% generate the vector of x values:
tickLocs = round(linspace(1,length(final_plot_mat_missing_part(2:end,1)),8));
% create an index vector (of logicals) that marks the columns to plot from the data matix:
validX = tickLocs(tickLocs<=325);
% plot only the relevant part of the data:
imagesc(transpose(all_area_for_visual(:,validX)));
% generate the correct ticks for the data that was plotted:
timeVector = final_plot_mat_missing_part(2:end,1);
timeForTicks = (timeVector(tickLocs(validX)))./60;
xticks(tickLocs(validX));
% here you continue with setting the labels, colormap and so on...
```